# Custom PostgreSQL with modified configuration files and database files stored on host’s filesystem?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I want to create a custom Docker image for PostgreSQL that will use the host’s filesystem for storing the database files.

I also need to adapt this image to override the default PGSQL configuration to enable accessing the database from any IPs. This is purely for a development environment so there are zero security worries or issues.

I know how to use the local filesystem and I know how to add a file from the host to the container. I don’t know how to do both of these things in the same image/container.

I tried using a Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:9.6.8
RUN echo "host all  all  0.0.0.0/0  trust" >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
```

With a compose file that includes:

```
version: "2"
services:
 db:
   image: "test-pgsql:latest"
   environment:
         - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
         - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgress
         - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
   ports:
         - "5433:5432"
   volumes:
         - /var/lib/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

This doesn’t work and I think it’s because the configuration files are modified inside the image but then the entire PGSQL folder is masked by the volume from the compose file.

Comment: Unrelated, but: putting `host all  all  0.0.0.0/0  trust` at the **end** of the file won't help. If a line before that prevents the connection, your addition will not be processed. That should be the **first** (or only) line in `pg_hba.conf`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can do this without creating a derivative image.

When the postgres image starts, it runs `docker-entrypoint.sh` (which is part of the image).

Part of this startup routine runs any scripts contained in folder `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

```
for f in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*; do
    case "$f" in
        *.sh)     echo "$0: running $f"; . "$f" ;;
        *.sql)    echo "$0: running $f"; "${psql[@]}" -f "$f"; echo ;;
        *.sql.gz) echo "$0: running $f"; gunzip -c "$f" | "${psql[@]}"; echo ;;
        *)        echo "$0: ignoring $f" ;;
    esac
    echo
done
```

As can be seen, it will blindly run any script in this directory that is either a `.sh` shell script, or a `.sql`/`.sql.gz` sql script.

Putting this all together, you could, in your `docker-compose.yml`, map a local folder (containing a shell script called something like `startup.sh`) to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`:

***`startup.sh`*** (you may need to add guards to prevent repeated appends to the conf files)

```
echo "host all  all  0.0.0.0/0  trust" >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
```

***`docker-compose.yml`***

```
db:
  image: postgres:9.6.8
  restart: always
  environment: 
    - SOMESTUFF=something
  ports:
    - "5433:5432"
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    - ${PWD}/postgresdocker/dbscripts/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Comment: I'd purposely avoided entry points because I thought I could avoid using them for now. This looks promising - great post, thanks. I'll mark it as the answer once I've tried entry points. It sounds like it will work but I want to try and learn about them first.

Comment: I had a brainwave over the weekend; read through the docker file for the PostgreSQL and re-read through the configuration files and realised the image is already configured to accept remote connections using MD5. So my mistake - I'd assumed it wasn't configured accordingly. I accepted your answer as I think it would work if the image wasn't already correctly configured. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeStoddart It had crossed my mind that I didn't need to go through these steps to configure postgres to be accessible to other docker nodes in my cluster. Sorry I forgot to mention it. The risks of taking a question too literally.

Comment: No problem; you taught me something I didn't know!